# xml error Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName

Tags: java, xml, web-services, wsdl, xsd

Here is my XML:

As suggested by many posts for the resolution, checked the closing tags..maybe I am still missing out something.Please help.

Also this is the SOAP request XML which I am taking as source to create the above xml:

Why am I doing this? I need to validate the request XML with an inline schema from a WSDL file, So I extracted the inline schema and created an XSD file.Now I need a request XML to validate against my already created XSD file.

Comment: Can you point out where the error occurs, line number on your editor? There must be some syntax mistake

Comment: Error is at Line no.2 - Element type "xmlns:ejb3" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". but I cant figure out where it wants me to put a closing tag.

Comment: You forgot to close the element may be. <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ejb3="http://ejb3.examples.itko.com/" />

Comment: @asok Buzz, the first xml is giving the error :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlns:ejb3="http://ejb3.examples.itko.com/">
 <ejb3:addUser>
           <username>abcd</username>
            <password>defg</password>
 </ejb3:addUser>
    </xmlns:ejb3>

Comment: Was not usng xmlns in the right way:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <ejb3:addUser xmlns:ejb3="http://ejb3.examples.itko.com/">
               <username>abcd</username>
                <password value1="test">6575</password>
     </ejb3:addUser> 

  

Got the error,thanks for trying!

Comment: Was not usng xmlns in the right way:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <ejb3:addUser xmlns:ejb3="http://ejb3.examples.itko.com/">
               <username>abcd</username>
                <password value1="test">6575</password>
     </ejb3:addUser> 

  

Got the error,thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, and to the use of XML.

You don't say exactly what the question is, but I guess it's something along the lines of "what is going wrong here?" or "what is wrong with this XML?"

The data you show is not XML, because it's not well-formed.  Consider the string `<xmlns:ejb3="http://ejb3.examples.itko.com/">`.  I guess this is intended to be a start-tag.

In XML, a start-tag begins and ends with angle brackets, and within those has an element type name followed by zero or more attribute-value specifications or namespace declarations, separated from each other and from the element type name by whitespace.

If we take the string `xmlns:ejb3="http://ejb3.examples.itko.com/"` as a namespace declaration (as it is, in the source from which you say you copied your data), then your problem is that your start-tag does not give any element type name.  (And a secondary problem is that the string `</xmlns:ejb3>` at the end of the data stream looks like it's trying to be an end-tag, but it's using a namespace-attribute name where it needs to be using an element type name.)

If on the other hand we take `<xmlns:ejb3` as an angle bracket followed by an element type name, your problems are that (a) the element type name begins with the reserved string 'xml', which is now allowed by the XML spec, and (b) the element type name is followed not by a closing angle bracket or by a blank and an attribute-value specification, but by an equals sign and a quoted string -- it looks like a fragmentary attribute-value specification lacking the attribute name.

Five minutes with a tutorial on the basics of XML should enable you to avoid such problems.  XML syntax is quite simple, compared to a lot of alternatives, but it is not something anyone is born knowing, and your experience shows that you are not managing to pick it up from examples without spending any time at all actually studying it.